# PHP's json_decode() with this JSON string

Tags: php, arrays, json, jsonlint

I have this JSON string:

```
 {
    "name": "test task1",
    "desc": "test desc1",
    "id": "1"
}{
    "name": "test task1aaaa",
    "desc": "test desc1",
    "id": "2"
}
```

But it looks like it's not correct ([JSONLint](http://www.jsonlint.com) tells me) so PHP's `json_decode()`can't decode it. There's any way to separate the two JSON arrays into two strings (or into how much string the arrays are) for making `json_decode` decode them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your intention is to have an array of two elements, your JSON should look like:

```
[
    {
        "name": "test task1",
        "desc": "test desc1",
        "id": "1"
    },{
        "name": "test task1aaaa",
        "desc": "test desc1",
        "id": "2"
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, just made it correct, was generating the array wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

the most straightforward

```
$str = ' {
    "name": "test task1",
    "desc": "test desc1",
    "id": "1"
}{
    "name": "test task1aaaa",
    "desc": "test desc1",
    "id": "2"
}';

var_dump(json_decode('['.str_replace('}{','},{',$str).']'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$str='{
    "name": "test task1",
    "desc": "test desc1",
    "id": "1"
}{
    "name": "test task1aaaa",
    "desc": "test desc1",
    "id": "2"
}';

$arrays = explode("{", $str);
foreach($arrays as &$arr) $arr='{'.$arr;

//decode
foreach ($arrays as $arr) print_r(json_decode($arr,true));
```